# Old movie about robotic crabs that eat metal, grow and reproduce

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I once saw a movie as described in the title, but don't know its name or how old it is. Please note, we are not talking about the original German movie from the 70's, *[Die Insel der Krebse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073171/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_9)*. I remember some scenes from it:

- A man gives his son a kit (robot crab), they assemble it, it comes to life, and runs to the wall socket and fries itself with its 'antennas'.
- Two people in a desert, where one is an Arab I think. There is a very small tent with a little crab under it.
- The crabs grow large, and start hunting people for metal in their clothing, such as zippers...
- Robot crabs (as big as a German VW Beetle car) hunt young people on an island.

It was live action, not animated. From what I remember, the audio was English. The robot crab effects were pretty well made for the time, the acting itself less good. I do not remember any actors, but I remember it to be a typical American made movie. I was quite young when I saw it, and I'd guess it was mid 80's - give or take. I'm also pretty sure it was a movie. It seemed long to me, but I might be wrong. In any case, it has left a lasting impression on me.

Comment: Color or black and white? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080933/

or this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_of_the_Crab_Monsters

Comment: I remember it as being in color. The crabs are robotic self reproducing machines. Not biological.
They look along the lines of a Delorian (car) with metal crab legs/claws. Metallic with edges.

Comment: Live action or animated? What language was the audio? Do you think the audio was the original audio, or dubbed in that language?  How long ago did you see it?  Are you certain it wasn't a TV episode rather than a feature film?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It was live action, not animated. From what I remember, the audio was English.
The robot crab effects were pretty well made for the time, the acting itself less good.
I do not remember any actors, but I remember it to be a typical american made movie.
I was quite young when I saw it, and I'd guess it was mid 80's - give or take.
I'm also pretty sure it was a movie. It seemed long to me, but I might be wrong.
In any case, it has left a lasting impression on me

Comment: Probably also not *Island Claws* (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080933/?ref_=tt_urv)

Comment: I scanned https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=giant-crab but no luck.

Comment: Maybe an adaptation of [Crabs on the Island](http://www.arvindguptatoys.com/arvindgupta/15r.pdf)

Comment: @Valorum, It looks like [*Krabi*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1945126) was based on the short story *Crabs on the Island*, but it's animated and short and doesn't fit the other plot parameters

Comment: What is the difference, comparing to the original "Die Insel der Krebse" movie? Is it not the same: https://www.amazon.de/Die-Insel-Krebse-Gerd-Baltus/dp/B074ZX9L55 ?

Comment: @SteveV you right: https://archive.org/stream/AnatolyDneprovCrabsOnTheIsland/Anatoly-Dneprov-Crabs-On-The-Island_djvu.txt

Answer (score 2):

The story, including details like the tent's "metal pegs" and "metal rings" (no zipper but even a character's "stainless steel false teeth"), is undoubtedly Anatoly Dneprov's Crabs on the Island / Island of the Crabs (Kraby idut po ostrovu, https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?925932 , available online).

The only known film of that is the short animated Krabi / Crabs (1976 dir Václav Mergl,

)

I suppose the original poster has a too vivid imagination and bad memory.